# Google Sheets: Count how many unique values appear more than X number of times

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Given a column of names I would like a formula to return a count of unique names that appear >=X number of times. The function COUNTUNIQUE works only if X=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=FILTER(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)>=2)
```

IF COUNT is more than 2,FILTER them in.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I had previously seen FILTER, but misunderstood it's function. Just for clarity in case others find this, the final formula is:


`=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)>=2))` Replace "2" with the number of times the value needs to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution to you problem. I am using a new column next to the column with the names to get a ranking.

[image]

formula to paste in B2 and drag drop to B11
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2;A2)

formula to paste in B16
=SUMPRODUCT(    (   ($B$2:$B$11)=B15  )  )

Comment: I have found similar solutions. This is good, but I was hoping to avoid adding new data like that. The holy grail would be solving this with a single formula in a single cell.